# opening URL in browser with python (not headless)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am not taking about headless browser.

I am writing an script, when a directory get a new file, it will open an url, when the file deleted from directory, it will open another url.

My Script is below:

```
import os, time


def folderListener(mydir):
    old_list = len(os.listdir(mydir))
    new_list = 0
    while True:
        new_list = len(os.listdir(mydir))
        if old_list != new_list:
            old_list = new_list
            print('OPen first url in chrom browser')
        else:
            print('Open 2nd URL in Chrome Browser')
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mydir = os.getcwd() + '/testdir'
    folderListener(mydir)
```

The script working very nice, now i need to it in the script when print function place. i mean, it should open an URL on Chrome Browser instead, no headless chrome browser.

Comment: `os.startfile(url)` (probably only Windows), `os.system("chrome url")`, `webbrowser.open(url)`, `selenium.webdriver.Chrome().get(url)`

Answer (score 1):

You could look into [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/webbrowser.html).

Used like:

```
import webbrowser

url = "http://mywebsite.com"

webbrowser.open_new(url) # open in default browser
webbrowser.get('safari').open_new(url) # open in safari if available
webbrowser.get('firefox').open_new_tab(url) # open in firefox if available
webbrowser.get(using='google-chrome').open_new(url) # open in chrome if available
```

But considering you tagged `selenium-webdriver` you could also do this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://mywebsite.com"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
```